# Problem with keycloak cors. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: flutter, jwt, cors, keycloak, websecurity

I use keycloak and hasura. I have a flutter web app. I retrive the JWT token from keycloak using flutter http. But I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms
/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 
'http://localhost:5050' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header
field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
in preflight response.
```

But when I use reqbin/curl and this curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data username=user \
  --data password=password \
  --data grant_type=password \
  --data client_id=hasura
```

it works.
This is my flutter code:

```
String url = 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token';

      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      };
    
      String body = 'username=user&password=password&grant_type=password&client_id=hasura';
    
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: body);
      print(response.body);
```

When I use `--web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"` it works fine. But I cannot use this I need this for production. My app will be in the closed local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix it. I set Web Origins: * and Valid Redirect URIs: *. Like in the image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt2US.png)

But the real problem is in flutter code - headers. I set headers in flutter to this:

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  };
```

This `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` should not be here. I remove him and all work.

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  };
```

So final flutter code is this:

```
String url = 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token';

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  };

  String body = 'username=user&password=password&grant_type=password&client_id=hasura';

  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: body);
  print(response.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS is a security mechanism provided by the common browser implementations.
That is the reason why you retrieve this error when using the browser, but not when using cURL.

To answer your question:

> http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:**8080**/auth/realms/**hasura-app**/protocol/openid-connect/token

> --data client_id=**hasura**

> 'http://localhost:**5050**' has been blocked by CORS policy

**Situation**

Given this information, I assume the following.
Your keycloak instance runs on port 8080. The realms name is hasura-app. Inside this realm you have a client hasura.

Your app accessing the authentication provider (keycloak) runs on port 5050.

**Explanation**

This error occurs because your url differs in the port-part (keycloak 8080, your app 5050). To avoid CORS-problems you need the same protocol, address and port. If anything differs, you will get an CORS error. For deeper insight consult rfc or owasp. From keycloaks perspective you need to allow every host, that want to consume it as auth-provider.

**Solution**

Login as admin, go to the realm hasura-app, go to clients and select your client hasura.

Inside the client you need to add the web-origin of your app by inserting the value, clicking the plus and save. Now the cors-error should disappear, however you likely would get a follow-up error saying invalid redirect_uri. That's why you can insert the same url, but with a "/*" as suffix in the Valid Redirect URIs section.

Comment: Valid Redirect URIs: http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/*  
Web Orgins: +  

But problem is not fixed. Still same issue.

Comment: Valid redirect uri: http://localhost:5050//*
Web-Origin: http://localhost:5050

Comment: But keycloak server is outside my network its hosted on digital ocean. This doesn't help

Comment: This should not play any role where your keycloak instance is hosted.
You apply these settings inside the client of the realm of your keycloak instance and when your flutter application tries to send a request it will be ok. That's why you should insert the address of the location of your flutter app. Then it is allowed.

Comment: Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:5050/*
Web Origins: http://localhost:5050
But still nothing

Comment: Can I unlock it for all? Security in this development phase is not crucial. Or disable CORS for all.

Comment: Sure, you can allow everything in development.

But in production, you need to explicitly allow only the URIs that should authenticate via your authentication provider.